# How to implement multiple assest paths for different themes in VueJS app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a VueJS app. It implements a multiple themes functionality. For that I'm using something like this:

```
let theme = getTheme() // returns 'light' | dark
document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', theme)
```

And color styles for the default(light) theme and for the dark theme

```
:root {
  --primary-color: #6B59CC;
  --primary-color-rgb: #{hexToRGB(#6B59CC)};

  --secondary-green-color: #009a76;
  --secondary-green-color-rgb: #{hexToRGB(#009a76)};

  --secondary-orange-color: #F6933E;
  --secondary-orange-color-rgb: #{hexToRGB(#F6933E)};
  ...
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --primary-color: #6B59CC;
  --primary-color-rgb: #{hexToRGB(#6B59CC)};

  --secondary-green-color: #009a76;
  --secondary-green-color-rgb: #{hexToRGB(#009a76)};

  --secondary-orange-color: #F6933E;
  --secondary-orange-color-rgb: #{hexToRGB(#F6933E)};
  ...
}
```

**NOTE: please don't mind that styles are the same for the both light and dark theme. This just an example.**

I need to use different icon color for each theme. For example: the light theme's base icon color is `#a8a8a8`, and for the dark theme's base icon color is `#cfcfcf`.

How to change icon's color dynamicly? Or there are multiple way to implement this in the world?

P.S. I use `SVG` icons with `object` tag. Like this:

```
<object :data="require('./assets/home.svg')" />
```

Comment: How can a user change the theme? by clicking a button or something?

Comment: yes, by clicking a button. then the data-theme will be changed.

Comment: did the answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about defining a variable in `data`; something like `lightTheme` and check that to change the theme:

```
data() {
    return {
        lightTheme: false
    }
},
methods: {
    changeTheme() {
        this.lightTheme = !lightTheme
        let icon = document.getElementById("id")
        if(this.lightTheme) {
            icon.classList.add('light-theme-style')
            icon.classList.remove('dark-theme-style')
        } else {
             icon.classList.add('dark-theme-style')
             icon.classList.remove('light-theme-style')
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to bind you'r element to `changeTheme`, If you want you can share you'r template code and i'll add it to the answer.